# Selecting SAP Fields using a Do Loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am working on a macro to go into SAP and select cells in a column to extract to excel. Now if this was excel, this would be no problem as I would simply use a do loop to travel down the column copying along the way. I am in SAP GUI however which is compatible with VBA and it is a little different. I recorded a script of me clicking down a column to see how the code changes. This is what I got.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,13]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,13]").caretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,14]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,14]").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,15]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,15]").caretPosition = 5
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,16]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,16]").caretPosition = 5
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,17]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,17]").caretPosition = 5
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

You can see that a particular value increases from 13 up to 17 as I moved down the column. I figured I could incorporate a do loop to then travel down the column and copy the values. Here is my relevant code

```
i = 13

Do

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
Current_Batch = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,i]").Text
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,i]").caretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

If Current_Batch = "" Then
Exit Do
End If

Cells(i - 11, 4) = Current_Batch


i = i + 1

Loop
```

This however does not work as it does not recognize the i as a variable. It gives me error 619 (could not find ID)

Does anyone know of a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I implemented the same kind of script. You need to construct your string, converting i to a string at the same time:

`session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12," & CStr(i) & "]").caretPosition = 6`

`CStr(i)` converts to string, while `&` concatenates strings together.

I only changed a single line, but you should be able to do it correctly, since you've identified your problem, so you have a grasp on how things work. Good luck,

Comment: Hey Jean, I was able to try your solution this morning and it worked, but one issue appeared where it stopped moving down the column the second it ran out of screen space. So the last batch it copied was the one at the bottom of my screen but this is a fairly long list that takes up multiple screen lengths. Do you happen to know a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Jordan I'm not sure I understand, could you provide more details ?

Comment: Sure, my screen is only able to fit about 1/3 of the column I am copying down. I noticed that it moves down the column and copies each value to excel until it reaches the bottom of my screen. Even though there is more data down the column, the code acts like it cannot "see" the data below and gives me error 619 again. I tried adjust my screen where I shifted down a few more lines (was only able to fit 2 more) It then was able to copy these as well so it must be going off of what it can "see"

Comment: It shouldn't be based on what it can see, it should be able to access these other values via script (we're talking about your SAP Gui screen interface right, when you're speaking about your screen). If it works like that (which I doubt a bit, having worked a bit with SAP scripting), you could add a routine in your code to scroll down the screen. If you do not know the code for it, just record it with VBA scripting just as you did for the first part. @Jordan

Comment: I agree that it is odd. I have had some weird experiences from the scripting in the past but it really does stop at the end of the visible interface. I will be adding a scrolling function later today to hopefully aid with the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried referring to the columns by name rather than by number?

Here is my loop that captures each column in a row and moves to the next

```
hRows = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").RowCount()
For h = 0 To hRows - 1 'Fill Dispatch Sheet at "A12"
    Cells(h + 12, 4).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getcellValue(h, "ERDAT")
    Cells(h + 12, 5).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getcellValue(h, "KTEXT")
    Cells(h + 12, 6).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getcellValue(h, "ERNAM")
    Cells(h + 12, 1).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getcellValue(h, "GEWRK")
    Cells(h + 12, 2).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getcellValue(h, "AUFNR")
    Cells(h + 12, 3).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getcellValue(h, "USTXT")
Next
```